# Проблема с арифметическими операциями c++

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся (похоже) с какой-то низкоуровневой проблемой преобразования типов (или еще чего-то).

Есть тривиальная функция линейной интерполяции Лагранжа:

```
unsigned char mix(unsigned char x0, unsigned char x1, float position){
    // LOGICALLY must be something like (implementation with casts)...
    return x0 + (x1 - x0) * position;
}
```

Параметры x0, x1 всегда в пределах 0-255
Параметр position всегда в пределах 0.0-1.0

По факту как бы я не пытался сделать касты параметров и привидение типов внутри метода, чтобы добиться такой логики, как описана выше не получается. Кто-нибудь знает, в чем может быть проблема? Компилирую под MSVC2017. Среда Windows10x64, Little-endian

Добавлено:
Похоже проблема шире, чем я предполагал изначально (судя по вашим ответам, спасибо за них). Вот ссылка на гитхаб на маленький проект, который демонстрирует проблему: https://github.com/elRadiance/altitudeMapVisualiser

Выходной файл bmp должен содержать карту высот с плавными переходами, а вместо этого содержит мусор. Если в функции интерполяции возвращать просто x0 или просто x1 - то все работает (но без переходов). В ином случае - мусор.

**Желаемый результат (как тут, но с плавными переходами)**
[image: Желаемый результат (как тут, но с плавными переходами)]

**Актуальный результат (самое лучшее, чего пока удалось добиться)**
[image: Актуальный результат (самое лучшее, чего пока удалось добиться)]

Main class чтобы запустить:

```
#include "Visualiser.h"


int main() {

unsigned int width = 512;
unsigned int height = 512;


float* altitudes = new float[width * height];

float c;

for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    c = (2.0f * w / width) - 1.0f;
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        altitudes[w*height + h] = c;
    }
}

Visualiser::visualiseAltitudeMap("gggggggggg.bmp", width, height, altitudes);

delete(altitudes);
}
```

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Вам нужно специально кастить дробный результат к целому. Вот эту `(x1 - x0) * position` часть

Comment: Что значит "не могли добиться"? Можно подробнее?  Может, вас просто отбрасывание дробной части, а не округление не устраивает?

Comment: http://tpcg.io/IomKCf - все правильно работает вроде-бы

Comment: `return std::round(x0 + (x1 - x0) * position);`?

Comment: Пример ожидаемого и реального результата приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил ссылку

Comment: еще немного улучшил актуальный результат: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elRadiance/altitudeMapVisualiser/master/best_result_achieved.bmp

Comment: Никаких проблем с вашей функцией `mix` не видно. Проблема в чем-то другом. Почему вы решили, что есть какая-то проблема с арифметикой в `mix`?

Comment: Проверьте еще раз входные значения функции `mix`. В самой функции все нормально. А заодно интерпретацию выходных значений остальной программой.

Comment: @AnT , решил, что проблема с арифметикой в mix потому , что если я в mix возвращаю x0 или x1 без интерполяции, то все работает правильно (см. картинку 1)

Comment: @Ternvein, пытаюсь уже неделю у меня там тонна _ASSERT, все проходят. Продолжаю попытки починить =)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрел ваш проект. Проблема не в функции `mix`, а в неправильной работе с файлом в бинарном режиме. Вы работаете примерно так (код упрощён):

```
ofstream file;
char buff = 10;

file.open("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc); //Проблема здесь;
file.write(&buff, sizeof(char));
file.close();
```

Попробуйте выполнить этот небольшой пример, а затем взгляните каков реальный размер созданного файла в байтах. Он может вас неприятно удивить.

Хотите работать с файлом в бинарном режиме, так открывайте его соответствующим образом:

```
file.open("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::binary);
```

---

В вашей программе, после применения функции `mix`, массив бинарных данных, который вы хотите побайтово записать в файл, содержит байты с значением `10`. `10` совпадает с ASCII кодом перевода строки (LF — line feed). При выводе в Windows он может заменяться на два байта, со значениями `13` и `10` — возврат каретки и перевод строки (CR и LF — carriage return и line feed).

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам! Это действительно был источник проблемы. Как я могу вас отблагодарить? =)